# Регулярное выражение для маски телефона

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Не могу никак догадаться как составить регулярное выражение для следующей маски:

```
+7 (301) ###-##-##
```

Составил вот такую, но она не правильная, т.к. маска может меняться в зависимости от города.

```
/^[+](7).+(\d{3,5}).+([#]{3}).+([#]{2}).+([#]{2})/g
```

Если немного изменяю регулярное выражение, то соответствия находит не правильные:

```
/^[+](7).+(\d{3,5}).+([#]{1,3}).+([#]{2}).+([#]{2})/g
```

В этом случае вместо первых ### я получаю всего одну решетку.

Мне нужно получить правильные соответствия, для дальнейшей обработки хранящихся в базе телефонов.

В базе телефоны хранятся в формате `73952969617`

Comment: Стандартный комментарий: пользователи вводят телефон, как хотят, путают ) и ], ставят пробелы вместо -, вас же через неделю попросят убрать маску. Нельзя сделать ничего толкового кроме гигантского парсера или проверки на наличие.

Comment: Удалите все не цифры и сравните длину строки с 10 (11). Маски - зло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понимаю, зачем писать так `[#]{2}`, если можно просто две решетки написать (да, в некоторых случаях нужно экранировать).

В целом, похоже что будут три варианта. Значит, нужно эти три варианта и записать

```
/^(\+(7).+(\d{3}).+(###).+(##).+(##))|(\+(7).+(\d{4}).+(##).+(##).+(##))/g
```

и дальше продолжайте как нужно.

кстати, `.+` - это любые символы, от 1 и до сколько влезет. А по вопросу нужно минусы. Странное выражение. Я бы писал где то так

```
/\+7\s*\(\d{3}\)\s*###-##-##|\+7\s*\(\d{4}\)\s*##-##-##/
```